# How to reload SmartTarget business manager/Fredhopper trigger configuration?

Tags: smarttarget, fredhopper

After adding triggers in the SmartTarget Business Manager/Fredhopper trigger configuration I know I should **reload the trigger configuration**. We can do that by restarting the query server or loading some admin page. What is the URL to the admin page to reload triggers?

Comment: I should know, forgot and could not easily find it in the documentation. This Q&A should make it easier to find.

Answer (score 10):

We Can achieve this using the following option in the FH/ST server :

`http://[host]:[port]/fredhopper/sysadmin/reload-config.jsp?select=trigger-types`

**although, the person who taught me that, told me that we need to be very careful with that administration console, we can mess up the entire environment**

Thanks Marc!

Comment: hi, We configure our trigger types in the Fredhopper and not the business manager. Would restarting the Fredhopper server will be a safer option  than using the above URL?